# VBA ByRef argument type mismatch of 'i' within a For Loop

Tags: vba, for-loop, type-mismatch

I'm calculating the present value of cash flows input by user in a column.  Column is of any length, so using .Rows.Count object as n parameter in the For Loop.

My question how to correct the type mismatch error:

ByRef argument type mismatch error pops when program gets to the i of the (r,c) identifier, line 6 of the following code:

```
    Function pvCf(cashFlows As Range, r)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
        n = cashFlows.Rows.Count
            For i = 1 To n
                pvCf = pvCf(i, 1) / Exp(r * i)
            Next i
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

`Function pvCf` is expecting a `Range` for its first argument:

This line is passing in an `Integer` to a function that is expecting a `Range`

> pvCf = pvCf(i, 1) / Exp(r * i)

The other caveat is that `Function pvCf` is making a recursive call to itself without a way to stop the recursion.   Once you fix the `Data Type Mismatch` and run the code, it will crash Excel.

As per Jeeped comments:

It appears that second appearance of `pvCf` should be changed to `cashFlows(i, 1)`

> ```
> pvCf = pvCf(i, 1) / Exp(r * i) 
>
> pvCf = cashFlows(i, 1) / Exp(r * i)
> ```

```
Function pvCf(cashFlows As Range, r)
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
    n = cashFlows.Rows.Count
        For i = 1 To n
            pvCf = pvCf(i, 1) / Exp(r * i)
        Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I was thinking the parameter should have been cashFlows.Cells(i) but I was worried about the recursion as well.

Comment: I bet that you are right `pvCf = cashFlows (i, 1) / Exp(r * i)` makes since.  No recursion like that. +1 Comment ..lol

Comment: Thanks so much!  long day entering formulas, the proposed fix did it.

Comment: @Jeeped should get half the credit.  But I'm keeping the Rep..lol